# How do I go back one page and refresh it using useNavigate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation

I want to go back one page and refresh it because I need a list to be updated and it doesn't do it when I'm just using the navigate(-1)

Code for example:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
    
function YourApp() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>go back</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to solve this partly.
To be able to refresh the list I wanted I used `Redux` and its `useSelector()` function.
The refresh page part is not possible yet because its not implemented into the navigator.

Btw: The functionality I was after is the equivalent of doing `window.location.reload().`

Answer (score 0):

You can set location to useEffect array:

```
const location = useLocation();

useEffect(() => {
    // your code
  }, [..., location, ...]);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using react-router v6

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const navigate = useNavigate();

const refreshPage = () => {
    navigate(0);
}
```